# SystemVerilog Assertion (SVA) Implication with Preemtive Start

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, assertion, system-verilog-assertions

I'm a newbie in SVA. I have a question about the SVA implication.

```
1: sequence s1;
2:   start ##[1:$] !start;
3: endsequence: s1
4:
5: sequence s2;
6:   ready && (!start);
7: endsequence: s2;
8: 
9: assert_ready: assert property (@(posedge clk) s1 |-> ##5 s2);
```

The purpose of this assertion is to check the timing property:

- when 'start' is toggled, 'ready' is activated after 5 clock cycle.
- But, when there is a preemtive 'start', that is, another 'start' toggle before 'ready' is activated, this timing property should be reset and the 'ready' should be muted.

I tried to verify this property by using the formal verification tool, Synopsys' VC formal. What it shows that this assertion fails because s2 sequence is zero when preemtive 'start' happens.

I think I have a wrong description at line 6, which is a real newbie code.  Would you please let me know how to describe the assertion for the preemtive start correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want

```
sequence s1;
   start ##1 !start [*5]
endsequence: s1
sequence s2;
  ready;
endsequence: s2;

assert_ready: assert property (@(posedge clk) s1 |->  s2);
```

Although you might have to adjust this depending on your requirement on what happens when `start` coincides with `ready` on the 5th cycle.

Comment: I checked it with VC Formal after some minor modification, and it's working well.  Thank you!